# How to disable weak cipher suits in java application server for ssl

Tags: encryption, java, cipher-selection, ciphers

I have a custom Java application server running. I am seeing that there are some weak cipher suites supported by the server, for example some 112-bit ciphers. I want to disable those. Where can I do that? Also, I want to enable TLSv1.2. The following is the code to initialize the socket:

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(sslstore), sslstorepass.toCharArray());
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    kmf.init(ks, sslcertpass.toCharArray());

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
    SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
    serverSocket = ssf.createServerSocket(port);

    System.out.println("Socket initialized");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JAVA allows cipher suites to be removed/excluded from use in the security policy file called **`java.security`** that’s located in your JRE: **`$PATH/[JRE]/lib/security`**  The **`jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`** property in the policy file controls TLS cipher selection. The **`jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms`** controls the algorithms you will come across in SSL certificates. Oracle has more information about this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#DisabledAlgorithms).

In the security policy file, if you entered the following: **`jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SHA1, DSA, RSA keySize < 4096`** It would make it, so that MD5, SHA1, DSA are never allowed, and RSA is allowed only if the key is at least 4096 bits. As for forcing TLS versions, this depends on your operating system (Linux, Solaris, Windows, BSD, etc), server (Apache, IIS, other)

Comment: Thanks it helped. Also I figured out how to solve the tls version issue also. Just have to put  `SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");` It will support all the versions.

Comment: Small note here, as 3DES is now weak as well you should also add "DESede" to the list above.